# useState counter flickers after clicking the button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
export const App2 =()=>{
     const [counter,setCounter]=useState(0)
     setTimeout(()=>setCounter(counter+1),1000)

  
     return(
         <div> {counter}
             <button onClick={()=>{setCounter(counter+1)}}> Plus</button>
         </div>

     )



 }
```

I recorded a video and uploaded it to [youtube](https://youtu.be/igT8W-B2Hzw). I have no idea why this instability happens and switching tabs made it normal again. Anyone to enlighten? I just made a slight modification to [this](https://fullstackopen.com/en/part1/component_state_event_handlers) code

Comment: It's because you create a new timeout every re-render, so you're essentially simulating `setInterval`. However, clicking the button causes an immediate re-render and thus creates *another* timeout. This means there'll be 2 timeouts waiting, one from the interval-like re-rendering, and one from the button click.  And both fire and cause the "double change" or flickering you're seeing.

Comment: A simple fix would be be a `setInterval` in a ref and just have it going in the background, not affected by re-rendering. You should also use the function argument to the state setter, as that makes sure the value is incremented using the correct previous state value, i.e. `setCounter(prevCounter  => prevCounter + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` causes an effect, so we should put it inside a `useEffect()` hook. Also, since setCounter depends on the previous counter state, we can pass an updater function to setCounter which receives the previous state value.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

export const App2 = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const increment = useCallback(() => {
    setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(increment, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, [increment]);

  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      {counter}
      <button onClick={increment}> Plus</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```